# Internet Explorer 9 about:tabs data location

Tags: internet-explorer-9

The Internet Explorer 9 `about:Tabs` page lists the most visited sites (or this is what it's supposed to do); however, it doesn't work as expected.

I came to several occasions where:

1. The list doesn't display the sites that I visit often
2. A recently visited page shows up in the list
3. The list is reset or many sites removed from it if Internet Explorer was forcibly closed

Where does Internet Explorer store the information about these sites? Is it possible to hack the list and force it to display the sites that you want/expect?

Comment: May I recommend that instead of just asking where this info is stored that you also tell us *why you want to know* - someone might then be able to provide a more direct answer to whatever problem/issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

> If a HTTPS-delivered page is delivered with the headers Cache-Control: no-cache, or Cache-Control: no-store, or Pragma: no-cache, IE will not add the page to the history list (it's been that way since IE5 for privacy reasons). Since the new tab page is built out of history, that's why those sites don't appear in the NTP.

[Source: EricLaw's IEInternals MS Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20151024153248/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/09/28/show-more-rows-of-sites-on-ie9-about-tabs-homepage.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my case has nothing to do with HTTPS or so. Some site I need to visit 100's times before they show up, and some show up from the first visit. Anyway, this is only one problem I'm facing. Read the rest of the question for other problems.